# Dispatch time forever in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, semaphore, dispatch

I have an app written in Swift 2. And there is a line like this.

```
semaphore.wait(timeout: dispatch_time_t(DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER));
```

but this line shows as an error in Swift 3. How can I convert this to Swift 3.

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can convert it like this `semaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)`